# Unable to Create Roles by Roles Resources "Custom" option type in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom, user-roles, access

We are Unable to access Roles Resources "Custom" option type in Magento 2 to add the custom roles.

When we select Custom option type, nothing is getting displayed. And also no issue is getting logged under Magento logs

Navigated to the following configuration in admin

```
System -> User Roles -> Add New Role -> Role Resource -> Resource Access select custom
```

Screenshot:

[image]

**Environment details:**

Magento ver. 2.1.3

PHP 7.0.14
OS: Red hat

Any help in this regard is appreciated.

Comment: Updated the question please check.